# Waiting for Observable subscribe to finish

Tags: rx-java

I'm currently learning how to use RxJava and I want to compute datas fetched from database and then compute them asynchronously but wait for all of them to be computed.

```
List<Data> list = getDatasFromDatabase();

list.forEach(data -> compute(data)); // How can I make this async using RxJava ?

// Here all Datas are computed
return list;
```

How can I make this blocking :

```
Observable.from(list).forEach(data -> compute(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toBlocking()` operator to create a `BlockingObservable`. However, I'm not clear on where or why you need it? If `compute()` is a synchronous method, your first solution will do everything you need, since it will process each item, one at a time, and be finished when the last `compute()` is finished.

If instead, you want `compute()` to be done asynchronously, then you might want:

```
Observable.from(list)
  .subscribeOn( backgroundThreadScheduler )
  .flatMap( data -> Observable.fromCallable( d -> compute(d) ) )
  .toList()
  .observeOn( foregroundScheduler )
  .subscribe( revisedList -> doSomethingWith( revisedList ) );
```

If you need `doSomethingWith()` to be done synchronously with the surrounding code, you can the `toBlocking()` operator just before the `subscriber()`. This step is not recommended, because you will end up blocking the foreground thread.